# getting code sign error when building iOS application

Tags: ios

getting this error when running app, it fails during buildtime.

```
/Users/USER/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/APPNAME-cqrknuczxqiiuxcvjlupnrmizjox/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TOCropViewControllerBundle.bundle: bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

Is it because there is a bundle within the cocoapods 'pods' folder?

```
CodeSign /Users/USER/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/APPNAME-cqrknuczxqiiuxcvjlupnrmizjox/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TOCropViewControllerBundle.bundle
    cd /Users/USER/APPNAME/Pods
    export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"

Signing Identity:     "-"

    /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign - --timestamp=none /Users/USER/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/APPNAME-cqrknuczxqiiuxcvjlupnrmizjox/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TOCropViewControllerBundle.bundle
```

Comment: 1. Delete Derived data
2. Clean the project
And try to run the project again.

Comment: @Wolverine tried that, didn't work. :(

Comment: @Wolverine added more of the error i forgot to add

Comment: try updating your cocoapod version and then install all the pod files and Clean and run the project.

Comment: tried that, didnt work as well.